# How to convert a list stored as a string to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I know the question sounds a bit vague, but this should clear it up.

```
a = "[200, 30.5, 37]" #This is a string literal, where a[0] = '['
b = [200, 30.5, 37] #This is a list literal, where b[0] = 200
```

How do I get b from a?

Answer (score -4):

```
b  = eval(a)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)